# HTTP "Ping-To" Headers - How can they be external URLs?

Tags: html, http-headers

PS: I don't know if this question is better suited for Server Fault, or Webmasters. If so, it can be moved.

---

In HTML5 there is a concept called [hyperlink auditing](https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/structured-client-side-storage.html#hyperlink-auditing), which can involve a `ping` attribute in a `a` hyperlink element. The use of which results in `Ping-To` and `Ping-From` HTTP request headers being received. All of the ones my site receives, the `Ping-From` value is a google search results page.

From what I understand, when these are present in a link to a given website, that website would receive the `Ping-To` HTTP header with the website's URL as the value.

99.9% of these `Ping-To` http request header values I am seeing are some url within the website. The other .1% are external URLs.

I have reviewed the w3.org spec for hyperlink auditing (linked above) and based on that, the `Ping-To` seems that it should always be the website receiving the `Ping-To` header.

> - **If both the address of the Document object containing the hyperlink being audited and the ping URL have the same origin** - 
>     The request must include a Ping-From HTTP header with, as its value, the address of the document containing the hyperlink, and a Ping-To HTTP header with, as its value, the address of the absolute URL of the target of the hyperlink. The request must not include a Referer (sic) HTTP header.
> - **Otherwise, if the origins are different, but the document containing the hyperlink being audited was not retrieved over an encrypted connection** - 
>     The request must include a Referer (sic) HTTP header [sic] with, as its value, the current address of the document containing the hyperlink, a Ping-From HTTP header with the same value, and a Ping-To HTTP header with, as its value, the address of the target of the hyperlink.
> - **Otherwise, the origins are different and the document containing the hyperlink being audited was retrieved over an encrypted connection** - 
>     The request must include a Ping-To HTTP header with, as its value, the address of the target of the hyperlink. The request must neither include a Referer (sic) HTTP header nor include a Ping-From HTTP header.

The external URLs I am seeing aren't linked from my site in any way, so I can't think of any other relation, other than they might show up in similar search engine search results pages as does my site.

So my data of values in `Ping-To` request headers might look like this, for example. The only way this would be related to my site is that it would for sure show up in search results for the query in the `Ping-From` value:

`Ping-From`:

```
https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=vi-us&biw=414&bih=622&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ZZwGWsrxF8OpjwTC56-IBg&q=denver+Carom+Billiard+Table+for+sale&oq=denver+Carom+Billiard+Table+for+sale&gs_l=mobile-gws-img.3...20443.29051.0.29760.14.12.2.0.0.0.140.1309.0j11.11.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-img..1.3.369...35i39k1j30i10k1.150.Pm80h9oyYco#imgrc=eCyr8UATa475QM:
```

`Ping-To`:

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/corner-pocket-billiards-wilton-manors
```

These are a pair of http headers on a single request that my site (which is not yelp.com) received.

What I don't understand is: **What does it mean when a received `Ping-To` header has a value of some other web site?** (what is the scenario occurring when I receive a `Ping-To` header with an external url as the value?)